# Why can't I get a specific value from a list in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to make a simple card game to get more used to classes in Kotlin, but something Is wrong, here's the code:

```
class Cards(val cardName: String = "", cardValue: Int = 0, amountDeck: Int = 4) {}

public var allCards = listOf<Cards>(
    Cards("One", 1),
    Cards("Two", 2),
    Cards("Three", 3),
    Cards("Four", 4),
    Cards("Five", 5),
    Cards("Six", 6),
    Cards("Seven", 7),
    Cards("Eight", 8),
    Cards("Nine", 9),
    Cards("Ten", 10),
    Cards("Eleven", 11),
    Cards("Twelve", 12),
    Cards("Ace", 10),
    Cards("Queen", 10),
    Cards("Jack", 10),
    Cards("King", 10)

)

fun drawCard(randomValue: Int) {
    val currentName: String = allCards[randomValue].cardName
    val currentValue: Int = allCards[randomValue].cardValue
}
```

I can get the `cardName` value from the list, but when I try to get the cardValue it just says: `unresolved reference: cardValue`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to put `val` before your second and third property names. If you omit that, it’s just a constructor parameter, not a property.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `val` before cardValue (and possibly amountDeck if you plan to use it). What you currently have only allows you to specify it in the constructor (a primary constructor parameter), but what you want is a class parameter.

```kotlin
class Cards(val cardName: String = "", val cardValue: Int = 0, val amountDeck: Int = 4)

Cards("One", 1).cardValue // works!
```

Comment: Woobs, didn't notice that I missed to put val before, thanks!

Comment: @NoelPettersson, consider accepting this answer as the correct one. Thanks!